# Not getting an email from Wordpress when changing the administration email

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to change my Wordpress Admin email but I'm not getting the email  that it said was sent. On the Settings page on Wordpress when logged in, I change to my mail. I am using AWS to host my Wordpress server.

What could be the problem here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to try with SMTP and send all email via SMTP.

Here some plugins of SMTP so install in your site and configure your SMTP details.

[Plugins - 1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

[Plugins - 2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/)